# Why do some numbers present the decimals and others don't?

Tags: c, floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning (disable:4996)

void cit_mat(float a[][100], int* m, int* n) {
    printf("nr linii =");
    scanf_s("%d", m);
    printf("\n");
    printf("nr coloane =");
    scanf_s("%d", n);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Introduceti matricea: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < *m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
            printf("x[%d][%d]=", i, j);
            scanf_s("%f", &a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

void ordonare(float a[][100], int m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int ok = 1;
        while (ok) {
            ok = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) {
                if (a[i][k] > a[i][k + 1]) {
                    int aux = a[i][k + 1];
                    a[i][k + 1] = a[i][k];
                    a[i][k] = aux;
                    ok = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void afis_mat(float a[][100], int m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%5.6f ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main() {
    int m, n;
    float a[100][100];
    cit_mat(a, &m, &n);
    ordonare(a, m, n);
    printf("Matricea cu liniile ordonate crescator arata astfel: \n");
    afis_mat(a, m, n);
}
```

Hi guys, so whenever I input decimals into this matrix (like 1.23, 1.45, 5.44), on the console, through the presentation of the matrix in the end there, only *some* numbers have the decimals, while some may appear as 4.0000, even though I have put it to be 4.55. What could cause this problem? I cannot figure it out. The code appears in Visual Studio 2019 btw.

Comment: In `ordonare`, `a` is a collection of floats. However you then do `int aux = a[i][k+1];`. When you store a `float` in an `int`, it is truncated to its integral part and the value after the decimal point is discarded.

Comment: @NathanPierson wow, not even in a hundred years could have I figured that out. Thanks for helping me out, I absolutely love this site. Cheers!

Comment: @NathanPierson Comment good enough as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ordonare`, `a` is a collection of floats. However you then do `int aux = a[i][k+1];`. When you store a `float` in an `int`, it is truncated to its integral part and the value after the decimal point is discarded.